# Strange matrix operation in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I've been trying to convert MATLAB code to Python and found this line of code which looks weird to me:

```matlab
S = favg(I+1);
```

Where `favg` is a 256-by-1 matrix, `I` is a 512-by-512 matrix and the result `S` is a 512-by-512 matrix.

Can anybody help me understand what `S` is?

Comment: @ThePyGuy Please don't use code formatting to highlight text. Code formatting is only for code (variable names, function names, etc.).

Comment: Read about MATLAB indexing here: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S` contains 512 x 512 elements of `favg` that are indexed by `I`.

A smaller example: `favg(4)` returns the fourth element of `favg`. `favg([1 3 2])` returns a row vector containing the first, the third and the second element.

Another example:

```
favg = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
I = [0 8]
S = favg(I + 1)
```

`S` contains two elements: the first element `1` and the last element `9`.